# IHTMLDocument2_write Causes Internet Explorer Security Pop Up - Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, ihtmldocument2

I have a Powershell script that opens an html file saved locally and parses the file. When it is run from the server where it was created it works fine. However, when I run it from the server where it will need to reside going forward, I keep getting an IE Security pop up. The code is:

```
$Source = Get-Content -Path $SrcFilePath -raw
$HTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
$HTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($Source) 
$results = $HTML.all.tags('table') | % OuterHtml
```

The variable $SrcFilePath is the path to where the HTML file is stored locally. When it gets to the line

```
$HTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($Source)
```

The pop up appears.
[image: IE Security Pop up]

Once I click "Close", the script resumes. The issue is, this script is going to be automated so no one will physically be around to click the "Close" button when it is appears.

I've tried creating a share to where the html file is saved and adding it to the Trusted sites in IE. I've changed the security level and I've also added about:security_scriptdriver64.exe to Local Intranet in IE, but none of these have worked. Any ideas?

**DETAILS UPDATE**
The server I'm running this on is Windows 2016 and the IE version is 11.

The html file I'm parsing is saved locally on the server i.e. E:\temp\webpage.html

When I created the share and added it to the trusted sites (I tried with both NetBIOS and FQDN), the option "Require server verification" was unchecked.

I've also tried adding about:security_scriptdriver64.exe to Trusted Sites.

I've also turned off "IE Enhanced Security Configuration" through Server Manager for both Admin and Users and this did not work.

**UPDATE 2**
I had mentioned in my last comment that I had put about:security_scriptdriver64.exe to Trusted Sites, tested, and it did not work. I started looking into using Invoke-WebRequest and playing with that. Was having issues so I thought I would go back to the IHTMLDocument2_write solution. I thought I would use a bare bones html file to start with that I had one table, with one row, and one column. My plan was to slowly start adding tags from the original html file to the barebones. I got as far as updating the title tag when I thought I would try again with the original. It worked.

I removed the about:security_scriptdriver64.exe from Trusted Sites and tried again. It still worked. I left it and everything worked fine so back to the drawing board.

I started again by adding that about line to Trusted Sites. Didn't work so started with the barebones HTML again. There is a block of JavaScript in the file. When I added it, to the barebones file, it didn't work. When I removed it, it worked. So, it's the JavaScript. I still don't understand why it started working last week. The HTML file is always generated with that JavaScript block. SMH.

Comment: Are you using the NetBIOS (without dots) or the FQDN (with dots) for the servername? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/intranet-site-identified-as-an-internet-site

Comment: I tried the NetBIOS and just tried the FQDN. I added the FQDN including the html file to the trusted sites and the pop up still came up. It was noted that the pop states it was blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Config. I turned that off for both users and admin and rebooted but still get the pop up.

Comment: Which version of the IE browser and which Windows Server OS you are using? Are you able to access that web page manually in the IE browser? If possible please try to share a sample of the path. you can replace the confidential information with dummy values. For testing purposes, go to the `Internet options-> Security tab-> Trusted sites`. Uncheck the option `Require server verification`. I suggest trying to save that file locally and add it to the share. Also, add it to a trusted site. See whether it helps to fix the popup issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I've added version information to my original post as well as additional info on what I have tried.

Comment: We can see that you had tried many things but the issue still persists. If possible, I suggest you reset the IE to its default settings and try to apply similar settings as IE on another server where it is working fine. See whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Here's something really odd...I had left about:security_scriptdriver64.exe in the Trusted Sites. I tested, and got the pop up. A couple of hours later, I tried again and it worked. I thought I would remove the setting in Trusted Sites to see if that was it, and it still worked. It worked for a whole week, then today, same thing. ***throwing my hands in the air***

Comment: I am not sure why it works for one week. To narrow down the issue I would suggest you just for testing purposes try to lower down the security settings of IE and see if it still shows the popup. If it does not show the popup then we can check for the options that can affect the result.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Okay, so Local Intranet was set to Medium-Low and Trusted Sites to Medium. I commented out the line that adds block comments to the script block, lowered Trusted Sites to medium-low and Local Intranet to low. Closed IE and ran the script and didn't get a pop up. I reset them and ran the script again. No pop up which I would have expected...in hindsight I should have ran the script first to confirm the pop up was still an issue after I commented the code out and before changing IE settings.

Comment: After changing the IE settings, try to restart the machine. Some settings get applied on startup.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - I tried that too :)